# Is there a good online free Java AWT tutorial?

Tags: java, awt

I'm looking for some good Java AWT tutorials on the Internet. Pretty much everything Google shows is about Swing and I need AWT because I need to use it for an exam. Unfortunately, books for the course aren't, to me at least, very clear on AWT use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the official Java tutorial for AWT? : http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/awt/contents.html

Comment: I'll take a look. Other "official Java tutorials" were good for me, but I couldn't find that one.

Answer (score 2):

This [one](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javawt/book/index.html) seems interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

THe first one only shows the "new java tutorial" which only covers swing.
The second one looks like it was an add for a book which is now out of print.

However, you can actualy click into each chapter, to read a pdf of each.
So it actualy is good. It's the old oreilly java awt book.

http://oreilly.com/openbook/javawt/book/index.html

Comment: It's the same book I linked to some time ago;